# Reverse django custom admin site URL

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I'm trying to get reverse for my custom admin which is using proxy model

```
class DeactivatedAdvertisements(Advertisement):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class DeactivatedAdvertisementsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ordering = ["-deactivated_at"]
    list_display = [
        "advertisement_title",
        "user",
        "root_category",
        "activate",
        "deactivated_at",
    ]
```

but I cann't find out how to reverse to sub page. In my panel admin, model Advertisement has few pages and I want to reverse to one of them.
I want to get url `admin/advertisement/deactivatedadvertisement/`

what I've already tried:

```
reverse("admin:app_list", args['advertisement', 'deactivatedadvertisements'])
```

How can I reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
reverse('admin:advertisement_deactivatedadvertisement_changelist')
```

(or possibly

```
reverse('admin:advertisement_deactivatedadvertisements_changelist')
```

if `deactivatedadvertisements` is plural)